# Case sensitive host volume mount in docker for windows

Tags: windows, docker

I am running a linux docker container on windows 10. I need my host to have access to the data that my container generates. I also need the data to persist if I update the container's image.

I created a folder on the host (On a NTFS formated drive), in the docker settings, I share that drive with docker. I then create the container with the host directory mounted (using the -v option on the docker run command)

The problem is that docker creates a cifs mount to my shared drive on the host. It seems like the CIFS protocol is not case sensitive. I create two files:

/data/Test
/data/test

But only one file will be generated. I setup the kernel to support case sensitive files. For example, if I mount the same folder inside cygwin bash, I can create those two files without any problem. The problem is with the CIFS implementation I think.

My current thoughts of solving this issue:

1. Use Cygwin to create an NFS server on the host, and mount the NFS volume from within the linux container. I am not sure how I can automate this processes though.
2. Create another linux container with a SAMBA server. Create a volume on that container:

   docker run -d -v /data --name dbstore --name a-samba-server

   Then use that volume in my container:

   docker run -d --volumes-from dbstore --name my-container my-container-image

   Then I need to share /data in the samba server and create a map to that share on my host.

Both solutions seem quite cumbersome and I would like to know if there is anyway I can solve this directly with the CIFS share that docker natively creates.